# ggplot2: how to read the scale transformation from a plot object

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-s4

I'm trying to extract information about the limits and transform of an existing ggplot object.  I'm getting close, but need some help.  Here's my code

```
data = data.frame(x=c(1,10,100),y=(c(1,10,100)))
p    = ggplot(data=data,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point()
p    = p + scale_y_log10()
q    = ggplot_build(p)
r    = q$panel$y_scales
trans.y = (q$panel$y_scales)[[1]]$trans$name
range.y = (q$panel$y_scales)[[1]]$rang
```

`print(trans.y)` gives me exactly what I want

```
[1] "log-10"
```

But `range.y` is a funky S4 object (see below).

```
> print(range.y)
Reference class object of class "Continuous"
Field "range":
[1] 0 2
> unclass(range.y)
<S4 Type Object>
attr(,".xData")
<environment: 0x11c9a0630>
```

I don't really understand S4 objects or how to query their attributes and methods.  Or, if I'm just going down the wrong rabbit hole here, a better solution would be great :)  In Matlab, I could just use the commands "get(gca,'YScale')" and "get(gca,'YLim')", so I wonder if I'm making this harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MikeWise points out in the comments, this all becomes a lot easier if you update `ggplot` to v2.0. It now uses `ggproto` objects instead of `proto`, and these are more convenient to get info from.

It's easy to find now what you need. Just printing `ggplot_build(p)` gives you a nice list of all that's there.

`ggplot_build(p)$panel$y_scales[[1]]$range` here gives you a ggproto object. You can see that contains several parts, one of which is `range` (again), which contains the data range. All the way down, you end up with:

```
ggplot_build(p)$panel$y_scales[[1]]$range$range

# [1] 0 2
```

Where 0 is 10^0 = 1 and 2 is 10^2 = 100.

Another way might be to just look it up in `$data` part like this:

```
apply(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]][1:2], 2, range)

#   y   x
# 1 0   1
# 2 1  10
# 3 2 100
```

You can also get the actual range of the plotting window with:

```
ggplot_build(p)$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range

[1] -0.1  2.1
```

Comment: Actually you have to point out that he is using ggplot2 version 1.0 which uses S4 objects. version 2.0 switched everything to ggproto objects and this is one of the benefits. This was actually quite hard to do in the old ggplot and is much easier now.

Comment: Yeah, me too, I wanted to answer it and went to a computer with the old version and couldn't figure out how to do it, even though it was really easy on my main computer. Check out what happens when you print out q too. You should post that.

Comment: Note that the old `proto` objects were S4 type objects, and `ggproto` are apparently not.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'm unfortunately stuck using ggplot2 1.0 for the moment.  I guess where I got confused was that I wasn't expecting to need to use "$range" twice in a row (though I see why, now) and I was looking for something that went c(1,100) instead of c(0,2).  But it all makes sense.  Thanks again!